# How to change the Library path in CMake MAC OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

**What I have tried**

I am working sample application using Caffe model in MAC OSX. I downloaded Caffe source from **https://github.com/BVLC/caffe**.
Steps:

1.Installed dependencies packages for caffe as said in Caffe Link. Some packages is in **/usr/local/lib** and some packages **/opt/local/lib**

2.Builded shared library(SO) file using CMakeLists.txt in CMake GUI.

3.Created sample c++ application

4.Linked all dependencies and caffe library files with c++ application.

5. Built the application

After I executed the application, It needed library files of dependencies package from **/usr/local/lib**

**What I want**

After I installed caffe dependencies, I copied all library files in another location.

How to link **specified location of the library** files in **Cmake.**?

In Mac osx, when the application run, It takes the library form **/usr/local/lib** not in the current folder(application folder).

How do I set the application to take library files from current folder.?

Comment: Are these caffe dependencies dynamic libraries (have the .dylib suffix)?

Comment: My understanding is that in OSX, dynamic libraries are stamped with their path so that when you build your application it will search in that location. You can change that with `install_name_tool`, but you want to do that before you build, otherwise the app will look in the wrong location.

Comment: And now that I think about it, does mac use .so files? I thought it just did .dylib...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All dynamic library extension had .dylib. I tried "install_name_tool".But i did not got it . Give sample for  changing lib path using "install_name_tool".?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a command from a makefile that I use to make an OSX application (the names have been changed to protect the innocent):

`install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/../Resources/libMyLib.dylib" ./libMyLib.dylib`

You can also just run `install_name_tool` on the command line.

The first argument after -id is the destination you want (including the name of the library) and the second is the current path to the library -- ie the binary itself. In this example the library is in the same folder as the makefile.

Then, after I build the app (the linker will include this new path to the desired library in the binary you build) I copy the library to the Resources folder:

`cp ./libMyLib.dylib App.app/Contents/Resources/`

In OSX-land `@executable_path` is whatever directory your actual binary is in. The way apps are packaged is like this:
`App.app/Contents/MacOS/App`. There is also a folder in `App.app/Contents` called `Resources`, and this is generally where I stash dependencies if I don't want the user to have to install them him/herself. Thus, in this case, `@executable_path/../Resources` is a relative path from the app's binary to where the dylib is going to be.

You can used `install_name_tool` to put the library anywhere you want. I just feel like this is a good place to do it.

By the way, you can check what the current id of the library is with `otool -L`. Probably, if you run

`> otool -L caffe.dylib`

it will return something like `/usr/local/lib`, even if you move it somewhere else. Try to change the id with `install_name_tool -id` and then run `otool -L` again, and see what happens. It should make sense at that point.

Comment: This is an execllent answer; it's surprising how buried this information is online.